# Is it permissible to omit "I" in conversation or informal writing?

Tags: grammar

Can I say or write sentences, in conversation or informal writing, without "I" like this?
Though not frequently, I might have heard native speakers saying without a subject, especially the pronoun "I".

> 1. A: What do you do in the evening?
>      B: (I) walk my dog to the bridge
>      right after having supper.
> 2. A: What do you do usually for fun? B: (I) read English literatures
>      every single day.

Comment: Yes, that is fine in conversation or informal writing. And you could also say "_Walking my dog ..._" and "_Reading English literature ..._" definitely without "I".

Comment: It is possible to omit the subject in *any* conversation, even one that is "formal", **if** it sounds right for the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This kind of elision, where the implied subject is clear from the previous sentence or other context, is very common in informal speech or written dialog. Less common but still quite possible in informal writing that is not dialog. (and that last sentence is an example, omitting "it is" or "such a construction is" at the start.)

By the way, the first example might well be further shortened:

> A: What do you do  evenings? B: Walk my dog to the bridge right after supper.